# Converting java date into sql date in jdbc

Tags: java, spring, date, jdbc, jdbctemplate

```
  for (final Object[] obj : leaveObjects) {
             for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
     try {

            jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
                public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(
                        Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql,
                            new String[] { "pk_CompOff_compOffId" });
                    ps.setInt(1,  (Integer)obj[0]);
                    ps.setInt(2,  (Integer)obj[1]);
                    ps.setInt(3,  (Integer)obj[2]);
                    ps.setInt(4, (Integer) obj[3]  );
                    try {
                        ps.setDate(5, new java.sql.Date(formatter.parse(obj[4].toString()).getTime()));
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

I am trying to save this  date from java to the database using spring jdbc template using the above code but getting this exception:

`java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sun Feb 15 00:00:00 PST 2015"` . 
i am using this formatter

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
```

How I can resolve that?

Comment: Can you show your code where you create the formatter?

Comment: the problem is your fomatter not, sql date

Comment: @chokdee formatter posted

Comment: @saurabh try this for your fomatter: `EEEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy`

Comment: Please search StackOverflow. You would have found hundreds of examples of working code to compare to your own.

Answer (score 0):

change :

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
```

to:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

**Note:**

1. a is replaced by z
2. commas are removed
3. some fields have chnaged places

`a` used for `AM/PM` where as `z` used for `Time zone` (e.g. **PST**)

For more reference, check this documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: I wonder if it was @chokdee who downvoted this answer.

Comment: @Tom beats me, I think answer is accurate with enough explaination...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Locale too, otherwise it will not run in every locale.

Try this

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);
```